# Convert from RSACryptoServiceProvider to RSACng

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I am currently using RSACryptoServiceProvider and I want to change to RSACng. I am using it to sign data. The reason for the change is that I am using Pkcs1 padding and I understand that Pss padding is preferred. We are undergoing security audits.

My question is how do I instantiate RSACng so that it uses the same private / public key each time?

With RSACryptoServiceProvider  I am doing:

```
CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();  
cp.KeyContainerName = "ContainerName";  
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);
```

passing in the container name means it uses the key that persists in the in the container store on the machine.

With RSACng, I tried this, but I get an exception: "The requested operation is not supported"

```
RSACng RSA = new RSACng(CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.Sha256, ContainerName));
```

I just need to be able to pass the store key name so it uses the same key each time instead of generating a new key.

Comment: Should the CngAlgorithm value be CngAlgorithm.Rsa?

Comment: Don't you need to use `CNGKey.Open` instead of `Create`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a named/persisted RSA key with CNG:

```
private static RSA CreatePersistedRSAKey(string name, int keySizeInBits)
{
    CngKeyCreationParameters creationParameters = new CngKeyCreationParameters
    {
        // This is what an ephemeral key would have had
        // (allows ExportParameters(true) to succeed). Adjust as desired.
        //
        // The default is not exportable (only applies to the private key)
        ExportPolicy =
            CngExportPolicies.AllowExport | CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport,
    };

    creationParameters.Parameters.Add(
        new CngProperty(
            "Length",
            BitConverter.GetBytes(keySizeInBits),
            CngPropertyOptions.Persist));

    // RSACng will extract the data it needs from this key object,
    // but doesn't take ownership
    using (CngKey key = CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm.Rsa, name, creationParameters))
    {
        return new RSACng(key);
    }
}
```

This skips the parts where you would do a try/catch around a call to CngKey.Open, or might want to delete the key (open it with CngKey.Open, and call Delete on the CngKey instance).

(`CngAlgorithm.Rsa` was added in net46.  If you're on an older version then an equivalent would be `new CngAlgorithm("RSA")`)