# RSACryptoServiceProvider vs RSACng

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa, cng

I have (non-exportable) keys which have been created using `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. I want to sign data using RSA-PSS (which is not `RSACryptoServiceProvider`). Therefore I want to obtain the same private key as an `RSACng` instance.

I tried the following:

```
// Create key with RSACryptoServiceProvider
var keyId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var providerName = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider";
var key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, new CspParameters(24) {
  ProviderName = providerName,
  KeyContainerName = keyId,
  KeyNumber = (int) KeyNumber.Signature,
  Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseNonExportableKey
});

// Obtain an RSACng reference:
var cngKey = CngKey.Open(keyId, new CngProvider(providerName));
var cngRsaKey = new RSACng(cngKey);

// Sign something using cngRsaKey
[...]
```

Unfortunately, it always fails when performing CngKey.Open with `WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset does not exist`.

How to open the previously created key with RSACng?

Note, that I cannot use the answer provided by https://stackoverflow.com/a/50703729/1400869 because I cannot use exportable private keys. In the end the keys should reside on an HSM (Hardware Security Module).

Any ideas?

Comment: See if this helps : http://www.infinitec.de/post/2010/11/22/Setting-the-PIN-of-a-smartcard-programmatically.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure how specifying a PIN programatically has anything to do with my question. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Sorry.  Working a smart card issue using RSA and got two post mixed up.  Still you are setting the provider in a certificate.  The PIN of a smartcard is the key in the certificate.  A smart card uses a certificate.

Comment: I'm only dealing with keys here, I don't see a certificate.

Comment: Then how does a key also have a provider name?  Don't you need a certificate loaded?

Comment: That /should/ work... does it work better if you use an Exchange key? (Since you’re making new keys with this snippet...) If not, what version of Windows are you on?

Comment: @bartonjs: Unfortunately, no. I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: After some more research, a colleague of mine pointed out that this is probably not possible at all using "normal" means. But! There is a procedure called "CngLightup" which obtains you a CngKey reference to a CSP (RSACryptoServiceProvider) reference. I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `CngKey.Open` doesn't work for CAPI RSA keys in the `Signature` slot (because it hard-codes the `dwLegacyKeySpec` value to `0`).  The easiest fix is to use the `Exchange` slot; but if you need to work with Signature-slot keys you can:

```
[DllImport("ncrypt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int NCryptOpenStorageProvider(
    out SafeNCryptProviderHandle phProvider,
    string pszProviderName,
    int dwFlags);

[DllImport("ncrypt.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int NCryptOpenKey(
    SafeNCryptProviderHandle hProvider,
    out SafeNCryptKeyHandle phKey,
    string pszKeyName,
    int dwLegacyKeySpec,
    CngKeyOpenOptions dwFlags);

private static void Test61275795()
{
    const string KeyId = "test-982375";

    CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters(24)
    {
        ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider",
        KeyContainerName = KeyId,
        KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Signature,
        Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseNonExportableKey,
    };

    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParams))
    {
        // Because this is a test, delete the key on Dispose.
        rsaCsp.PersistKeyInCsp = false;

        SafeNCryptKeyHandle hKey;

        int dwError = NCryptOpenStorageProvider(out var hProv, cspParams.ProviderName, 0);

        using (hProv)
        {
            if (dwError != 0)
            {
                throw new CryptographicException(
                    $"{nameof(NCryptOpenStorageProvider)}: 0x{dwError:X8}");
            }

            dwError = NCryptOpenKey(hProv, out hKey, KeyId, cspParams.KeyNumber, 0);

            if (dwError != 0)
            {
                hKey.Dispose();
                throw new CryptographicException($"{nameof(NCryptOpenKey)}: 0x{dwError:X8}");
            }
        }

        using (hKey)
        using (CngKey cngKey = CngKey.Open(hKey, 0))
        using (RSACng rsaCng = new RSACng(cngKey))
        {
            byte[] sig = rsaCng.SignData(
                Array.Empty<byte>(),
                HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
                RSASignaturePadding.Pss);

            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(sig));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer!

Answer (score -1):

There is a procedure called "CngLightup" which allows one to obtain a RSACng reference to a key created with RSACryptoServiceProvider. It is used by Microsoft, e.g., in their implementation of manifest signing: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/inc/mansign2.cs#L1426

This requires you to have a certificate in your hands, not just a key reference. But it is easy to create a dummy self-signed certificate using the key at hand, then call CngLightup.GetRSAPrivateKey() and voila, if you check GetType(), you have an RSACng reference in your hands.

Comment: CngLightup is just a helper utility for inside the framework to understand if it's "safe" to call (e.g.) `cert.GetRSAPrivateKey()` and do what's expected for the system; which is just due to how .NET 4.5.2 (no RSACng) and later versions (yes RSACng) handle sharing a GAC.  The difference is in the plumbing behind `GetRSAPrivateKey()`, which I worked around in my answer.